# 301 Redirect in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, https, shopify

I'm building an external app, and upon loading the app for the first time in needs to redirect to a shopify link so that the user can give my app permissions. Currently, I'm doing it like this:
`<Navigate to="{url}" />` , where {url} is the correct url that my app should be redirecting to. But nothing happens. Am I missing something? How do you properly redirect to an external webpage and get a 301 status code using React?

Comment: if you want to navigate to external url try `window.location.href={url}`

Comment: It's not possible to declare status codes with the frontend (React). Anyways, no one can help you if you don't share your code, so please edit your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).